# Erro ao usar o npm no Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou com um problema quando vou tentar iniciar uma aplicação usando o nodejs no Windows 10. Toda vez que uso qualquer comando do npm(tirando o -v) o seguinte erro é exibido

> ```
> Error: Cannot find module 'verror'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\jsprim\lib\jsprim.js:9:18)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
> npm ERR! node v6.11.0
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
> npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
> ```

```
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'verror'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Já configurei nas variáveis de ambientes os caminhos do node

- C:\Program Files\nodejs

e do npm

- C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm

Alguém tem algum ideia?

Comment: Meus poderes de leitura e compreensão indicam que falta um módulo chamado [verror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verror) na sua aplicação.

Comment: já tentou um `npm install` no diretório onde está o `package.json`?

Comment: Olá @LucasCosta, sim dei um npm install dentro da pasta onde possui o package.json.

Comment: Olá @Renan como disse no inicio do tópico esse erro em todos os comandos, inclusive se tentar instalar o  verror... Segue:  npm install verror
Error: Cannot find module 'verror'

Comment: Está usando qual versão do node? Verifique se é compativel com a arquitetura do seu SO e tente usar sempre uma versão estável

Comment: Estou usando 6.11

Comment: @cido18 eu recomendo desinstalar e reinstalar o node. Se não der certo, tente uma versão anterior, ou coloque o *verror* manualmente no ambiente.

Comment: @Renan funcionou para o verror, mas agora outros módulos estão sendo pedidos... existe alguma outra maneira de instalar todos os componentes do node de uma vez? Pois ficar baixando item por item vai ser demorado...

Comment: @cido18 desinstala o noje e instala de novo.

Comment: Obrigado LucasCosta e @Renan basicamente só precisei adicionar os modulos em C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm  manualmente e funcionou.

Comment: @cido18 agora que eu entendi o problema que você teve que corrigir eu reverti o meu voto (-1 para +1).